# ping and traceroute not running despite I'm connecting to internet

Tags: ping, traceroute

I'm under firewall, I'm using linux, I try `ping www.google.com` and `traceroute www.google.com`. traceroute reach gateway and ping give nothing dispide I'm connecting to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you ping any other address? If no, then perhaps the Firewall you're behind is configured to block ICMP packets. Both Ping and Traceroute rely on ICMP, so if it's blocked, you won't be able to perform them successfully.

Comment: I can't ping to any IP address, after research I think that you're right, my firewall block ICMP packets,thanks

Comment: You should get that fixed. ICMP is not optional -- it is required for TCP/IP to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall does not only filter ICMP but UDP as well. Per default, Linux traceroute uses UDP for probes - not ICMP. Moreover, you can use TCP SYN with option `-T`, UDP Lite with `-UL` or request ICMP echo like ping with `-I`. Option `-p` sends the probe to and option `--sport` from a specific port.

I suggest you try to probe an IP address without resolving the domain name first. Here are some addresses used for Google Search: 173.194.116.115, 173.194.116.114 , 173.194.116.113, 173.194.116.112.